# How to assign only one resource a IP4 adress for Docker Containers in Terraform?

Tags: docker, terraform

If i apply this in Terraform it says: " Unable to start container: Error response from daemon: Address already in use"

I checked and the listener got the IP 10.0.1.1 - but why?
I don't want to assign fixed Addresses to the listener because there could be varying amounts of listeners and talkers (not included in example).

```
# Setting up docker network
resource "docker_network" "private_network" {
  name       = "vaccine-net"
  attachable = true
  ipam_config {
    subnet  = "10.0.1.0/24"
    gateway = "10.0.1.254"
  }
}

# create container
resource "docker_container" "bootstrapper" {
  name  = "bootstrapper"
  image = "vaccine/bootstrapper:latest"
  networks_advanced {
    name         = docker_network.private_network.name
    ipv4_address = "10.0.1.1"
  }
}

# create Docker vaccine-listener
resource "docker_container" "vaccine-listener" {
  name  = "listener-${(count.index) + 1}"
  image = "vaccine/listener:latest"
  count = 1
  networks_advanced {
    name = docker_network.private_network.name
  }
}
```

Edit: I tried giving everyone a fixed IP via ipv4_address = "10.0.1.X" and it worked. But i only want to set the Bootstrapper IP Manually.

Comment: If you don't want it to reuse that IP address why are you specifying it? The default behaviour without setting the `ipv4_address` parameter should be that the network assigns an IP address to the container via DHCP.

Comment: I'm not sure I need this address for the Bootstrapper. But i think what's happening here is, that DHCP gives this Adress to the listener First! How can i prevent that ?

Comment: Anyone an Idea?

Comment: Until someone finds a better solution, i added depends_on = [docker_container.bootstrapper] to the listener ...